# Looping over lenses, and using each with view and set

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

This is a version of some code I have been working on, with the specifics removed. Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to do, but if not I can clarify. I'm quite new to using lenses, and the complicated types involved often make them seem more trouble than they're worth.

```
-- some data type
type AType = ...

data Thing = Th { _v, _w, _x :: AType, _otherStuff :: ... }

makeLenses ''Thing

-- some operation that can be performed on corresponding x or w or v values in two Things.
f :: AType -> AType -> AType
f = ...

-- apply f to the corresponding v, and w, and x values in a and b; then store each result in the respective field of a, leaving other fields untouched.
transform :: Thing -> Thing -> Thing
transform a b =
    let transformVorWorX :: Lens' Thing AType -> AType
        transformVorWorX lens = 
            let vwx  = view lens a
                vwx' = view lens b
            in  f vwx vwx'

    in  foldl (\a' lens -> set lens (transformVorWorX lens) a') a [v,w,x]
```

When I compile, ghc spits out

```
Could not deduce (f ~ Identity)
from the context (Functor f)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             Functor f => (AType -> f AType) -> Thing -> f Thing
  at ...
  ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context:
        Functor f => (AType -> f AType) -> Thing -> f Thing
      at ...
Expected type: (AType -> f AType) -> Thing -> f Thing
  Actual type: ASetter Thing Thing AType AType
In the first argument of ‘transformVorWorX’, namely ‘lens’
In the second argument of ‘set’, namely ‘(transformVorWorX lens)’
```

Why doesn't this code work? I found that replacing `lens` with `cloneLens lens` lets it compile, but I'm not sure why, and this feels very ugly - is there a more elegant way to do what I want, that is perhaps more general?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Lens'` is under the hood universally quantified

```
type Lens' s a = ∀ f . Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

So the type of `[v,w,x]` would have to be

```
[∀ f . Functor f => (AType -> f AType) -> Thing -> f Thing]
```

– with a quantor *inside the list*. Such types are called [impredicative types](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ImpredicativePolymorphism), and Haskell doesn't support them. (A GHC extension with that name has been around for a while, but it doesn't work.) [**Edit**: work on impredicatives [is ongoing](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3408971) as of 2021.]

There's a relatively easy way that always works to get around this: hide the quantor in a `newtype`. In the lens library, this is [`ReifiedLens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedLens). With it you can write

```
transform a b =
    let transformVorWorX :: ReifiedLens' Thing AType -> AType
        transformVorWorX (Lens lens) = 
            let vwx  = view lens a
                vwx' = view lens b
            in  f vwx vwx'
    in  foldl (\a' lens -> set (runLens lens) (transformVorWorX lens) a') a
            [Lens v, Lens w, Lens x]
```

This code has exactly the runtime behaviour of the one you envisioned, but it's clearly pretty ugly.

The alternative solution you've discovered yourself does *effectively* the same thing too but is rather nicer. To see what's actually going on there, I'll put the `cloneLens` within `transformVorWorX`:

```
transform a b =
    let transformVorWorX :: ALens' Thing AType -> AType
        transformVorWorX lens = 
            let vwx  = view (cloneLens lens) a
                vwx' = view (cloneLens lens) b
            in  f vwx vwx'
    in  foldl (\a' lens -> set (cloneLens lens) (transformVorWorX lens) a') a [v,w,x]
```

The reason this works is that, like `ReifiedLens` – but unlike `Lens` – [`ALens'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:ALens) has no quantor. It is just a concrete instantiation of the `Functor f`, thus it doesn't require impredicativity but you can directly use `v`, `w` and `x` in a `[ALens' Thing AType]` list. The functor instance is cleverly chosen to *not lose any of the generality*, hence `cloneLens` is able to give you back a full, universally-quantised lens.

Rather than cloning it, you can also use the [`^#`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-94--35-) operator, which directly views an `ALens`, and [`storing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:storing) instead of `set`:

```
transform a b =
    let transformVorWorX :: ALens' Thing AType -> AType
        transformVorWorX lens = 
            let vwx  = a^#lens
                vwx' = b^#lens
            in  f vwx vwx'
    in  foldl (\a' lens -> storing lens (transformVorWorX lens) a') a [v,w,x]
```

If we condense that to a less verbose form, it looks quite good IMO:

```
transform a b = foldl updater a [v,w,x]
 where updater a' lens = a' & lens #~ f (a^#lens) (b^#lens)
```

---

Let me also suggest an entirely different solution: you define **a single optic that accesses *all* the values of interest**, namely

```
vwx :: Traversal' Thing AType
vwx f (Thing в ш к otherVals)
    = (\в' ш' к' -> Thing в' ш' к' otherVals)
      <$> f в <*> f ш <*> f к
```

Instead than defining this yourself, you can also let the Template Haskell helper do it for you:

```
makeLensesFor [("_v", "vwx"), ("_w", "vwx"), ("_x", "vwx")] ''Thing
```

Now, a traversal can be used as a simple fold, and thus [to get a *list*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94-..) of all the values. You can then use a standard zip to perform the transformation of the elements:

```
transform a b = ...
 where tfmedVals = zipWith f (a^..vwx) (b^..vwx)
```

To put that list of modified values back in a container, the library has also a function: [`partsOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:partsOf). And with that, your entire transformation boils down to

```
transform a b = a & partsOf vwx .~ zipWith f (a^..vwx) (b^..vwx)
```

Comment: It appears that I missed your answer back in 2017. But thank you. I hope it has helped someone else. I must admit Lenses are still mysterious to me, these days I am on the dark side doing C++...